# Reusing Image Movieclips

Tags: flash, actionscript

What I want to do is build WALL of images, say of 2 random images.

X0X0X0X0X0 (where X and O are the images.)

Now to load these I normally would use a for loop such as (code isnt exact, but hope u get the idea)

```
imageArray = "X", "O";

for (x = 0; x < numberOfImagesInWall; x++){

randomNum = random(2)

imageName = imageArray[randomNum];

loadimage (imageName)

.....etc....

}
```

When I use this method I find it loads the images EACH time for X and O.  I am wondering if there is a way I can preload the image of X and O and just reuse them anytime I want, where no loading is involved.

Comment: Have a look at BitmapData and the clone method.

Comment: Im looking but just wish there was a small nice tutorial on it

Answer (score 0):

try this!

```
var images:Array = [img1, img2];//u will obviously need to populate this with real images
var pos:int = 0;
var newX:int = 0;

for(var i:int = 0; i < numberOfImagesInWall; i++)
{
    var bd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(images[pos].width, images[pos].height, true, 0x00000000);
    bd.draw(images[pos]); 
    var b:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bd);
    addChild(b);
    b.x = newX;
    newX += b.width;

    if(pos == 0)
        pos++;
    else
        pos = 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var images.Array=[new Image1().bitmapData,new Image2().bitmapData]; // adjust for your case
// this syntax is valid if you have Image1 and Image2 in your library, as bitmap images
for (var i:int=0;i< numberOfImagesInWall; i++)
{
    var b:Bitmap=new Bitmap(images[Math.floor(Math.random()*2.0)]); 
        // provide existing BitmapData as source for the image
    b.x=getX(i);
    b.y=getY(i); // give coordinates as you need it
    addChild(b);
}
```

Providing existing BitmapData as link to all the Bitmaps has a benefit of low memory consumption, and an ability to change all the relevant Bitmaps by a single operation over the referred BitmapData. So, if, for example, you do `images[0].fillRect(images[0].rect,0xffff0000)` then half of your walled Bitmaps will turn red without extra effort.